# add custom filter class in applicationcontext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

my application is using spring applicationContext.xml. i have a custom filter class ( CustomFilter implements Filter) that i want to use in my application . Is the proper way to do this is to create a `<bean...` registration inside applicationContext.xml ? or simple just put inside web.xml ? i want to put inside applicationContext.xml. but i do not know how to specify "path" that will trigger this filter. example `myapp/testcustomfilter` will trigger this filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FilterToBeanProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/util/FilterToBeanProxy.html)  class proxies request to spring managed beans. You have to define  this filter in your web.xml and point targetBean parameter to your managed-bean. Also check out the [FilterChainProxy](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/util/FilterChainProxy.html) to define a filter chain.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter class can reside in `applicationContext.xml`, and be treated like any other Spring bean.  However, you need to add something to the `web.xml` to allow the server container to get a handle on it.

This is where Spring's `DelegatingFilterProxy` comes in.  From the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html):

> Proxy for a standard Servlet 2.3 Filter, delegating to a Spring-managed bean that implements the Filter interface. Supports a "targetBeanName" filter init-param in web.xml, specifying the name of the target bean in the Spring application context.
>
> web.xml will usually contain a DelegatingFilterProxy definition, with the specified filter-name corresponding to a bean name in Spring's root application context. All calls to the filter proxy will then be delegated to that bean in the Spring context, which is required to implement the standard Servlet 2.3 Filter interface.
>
> This approach is particularly useful for Filter implementation with complex setup needs, allowing to apply the full Spring bean definition machinery to Filter instances.

The simplest setup is to define a `DelegatingFilterProxy` filter in `web.xml` with the same name as the filter bean in `applicationContext.xml`. `DelegatingFilterProxy` will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Just registering your `Filter` in `web.xml` works just fine.  We have a mixture of non-Spring and Spring filters in our application (the non-Spring filters are legacy code), and they all play nicely together.  It also makes maintenance easier because you only need to look in one location to see how things chain together, because by definition the order in `web.xml` is the order of execution.